# identifier expected, too few arguments to function (C)

Tags: c

My code:
I have tried multiple ways to fix this but to no avail.
I have to use `scanf` in the code so I cannot replace it with `fgets` as many people have told me to.
Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

float Parallel(float R1, float R2);

void main(void) {
    char circ;
    float R1, R2, R3;
    
    printf("Select Circuit [A/B/X]: ");
    scanf("%c", &circ);
    
    if (circ == 'A') {
        printf("Enter R1 and R2: ");
        scanf("%f%f", &R1, &R2);
        printf("%f%f", R1, R2);
        Parallel(float R1, float R2);
        printf("Total resistance for Circuit A is %.2f Ohm", RT);
    }
    
    if (circ == 'B') {
        printf("Enter R1, R2 and R3: ");
        scanf("%f%f%f", &R1, &R2, &R3);
        Parallel(float R1, float R2);
        RT = RT + R3;
        printf("Total resistance for Circuit B is %.2f Ohm", RT);
    }

    if (circ == 'X') {
        printf("That's All");
    }
}
        
float Parallel(float R1, float R2);
{
    float RT;
    RT = 1 / (1 / R1 + 1 / R2);
    return RT;
}
```

Comment: You should tell us what's wrong with the code. What errors do you get, what is the problem, etc.

Comment: Although `Parallel(float R1, float R2);` is not how you call a function, which any introduction level C book/tutorial should have taught you. But even if you fix that, you just completely ignore the return value as well, making the call useless

Comment: Remove the `;` from the definition of `Parallel` (at the bottom of the posted code).  As it is, the semicolon makes it a forward declaration, followed by an unexpected function body.  Also, in `main`, the two references to `Parallel(float R1, float R2);` aren't function calls.  They merely declare `Parallel` yet again, with an implicit `int` return type.  Get rid of the `float` in the arguments to make them function calls.

Comment: `float RT;` is a local variable in the `Parallel` function. You can't use it outside the function since it doesn't exist. This is an error in addition to not actually calling the function and other errors.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in the definition of `Parallel`: the extra `;` should be removed. Putting the `{` on the same line would have made this mistake obvious:

```
float Parallel(float R1, float R2) {
    float RT;
    RT = 1 / (1 / R1 + 1 / R2);
    return RT;
}
```

The calls to the function `Parallel` are incorrect too: `Parallel(float R1, float R2)` should be changed to:

```
    RT = Parallel(R1, R2);
```

Also note that `main` must be defined with a return type of `int`.

Here is a modified version with a loop to perform tasks iteratively:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float Parallel(float R1, float R2);

int main() {
    char circ;
    float R1, R2, R3;
    
    for (;;) {
        printf("Select Circuit [A/B/X]: ");
        if (scanf(" %c", &circ) != 1)
            return 1;
    
        if (circ == 'A') {
            printf("Enter R1 and R2: ");
            if (scanf("%f%f", &R1, &R2) != 2)
                return 1;
            printf("%f%f", R1, R2);
            RT = Parallel(R1, R2);
            printf("Total resistance for Circuit A is %.2f Ohm\n", RT);
        } else
        if (circ == 'B') {
            printf("Enter R1, R2 and R3: ");
            if (scanf("%f%f%f", &R1, &R2, &R3) != 3)
                return 1;
            RT = Parallel(R1, R2);
            RT = RT + R3;
            printf("Total resistance for Circuit B is %.2f Ohm\n", RT);
        } else
        if (circ == 'X') {
            printf("That's All\n");
            return 0;
        } else {
            printf("Invalid option\n");
        }
    }
}
        
float Parallel(float R1, float R2) {
    float RT;
    RT = 1 / (1 / R1 + 1 / R2);
    return RT;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace 2 occurrences of `Parallel(float R1, float R2);` with `float RT=Parallel(R1,R2);`.
As pointed out by others, the code you have is not how to call a function nor do you use the result.

Remove a stray semi-colon in the line `float Parallel(float R1, float R2);` toward the end of the code.
The one at the start is correct in a prototype but not in a function definition.

Amend the line `void main(void)` to `int main(void)` and add `return 0;` to the end of `main()`. You may not want a return value but this keeps C sweet. ;)

PS: It's a long time since I studied electricity. I can't validate you calculations!

```
#include <stdio.h>
float Parallel(float R1, float R2);
int main(void)
{
    char circ;
    float R1, R2, R3;
    
    printf("Select Circuit [A/B/X]: ");
    scanf("%c", &circ);
    
    if(circ == 'A')
    {
        printf("Enter R1 and R2: ");
        scanf("%f%f", &R1, &R2);
        printf("%f%f", R1, R2);
        float RT=Parallel(R1,R2);
        printf("Total resistance for Circuit A is %.2f Ohm", RT);
    }
    
    if(circ == 'B')
    {
        printf("Enter R1, R2 and R3: ");
        scanf("%f%f%f", &R1, &R2, &R3);
        float RT=Parallel(R1,R2);
        RT = RT + R3;
        printf("Total resistance for Circuit B is %.2f Ohm", RT);
    }

    if(circ == 'X')
    {
        printf("That's All");
    }
    return 0;
}
    
float Parallel(float R1, float R2)
{
    float RT;
    RT = 1/(1/R1+1/R2);
    return RT;
}
```